# Suggested edits pending approval indicator lights when I exceeded daily review limit

Tags: support, review, rate-limiting

Recently top-bar started to feature indicator with number of pending reviews [actually it seems that it shows number of suggested edits approvals only, not sure]. That's good.

But why does it appear even after I have exceeded daily review limit? It's distracting, especially as it appears/disappears very frequently.

Is it a [kind-of] bug or does it have a purpose that I'm missing?

[image: suggested edits review queue]

Comment: no free-hand circles?

Comment: @OGHaza Thanks. I wasn't able to find it (I tried) before asking. Anyway, it's not really resolved, imho.

Comment: Sorry, but if you click it and see that message more than once then perhaps your attention-span needs attention?  When I've run out and see that limit my brain tells me not to click again... ;)